# Autofac Resolve all registered instances by runtime provided Type

Tags: c#, autofac

Given a type provided at runtime such as:

```
var type = typeof(IMyType);
```

Does Autofac have the ability to Resolve all registered instances of that type? e.g. I'm looking for something like this (without Generics):

```
container.ResolveMany(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can resolve a collection of that type.

Something like this:

```
var type = typeof(IMyType);
var collectionType = typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var resolvedTypes = container.Resolve(collectionType);
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u7WQDh)

However, because `type` is only known at runtime, to do anything with the resolved instances you would need to use reflection. The only compile time cast that could be performed would be to `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: I actually tried this earlier and it didn't seem to be working, I must have messed something up. I'll give it another go, thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to cast to `IReadOnlyCollection<IMyType>` in that last line if you don't know the `IMyType`. Like, if you had a method signature, it'd be more like `private IEnumerable<object> ResolveAll(Type myType)` because the best you could do is cast to `object` without knowing the type at compile time.

Comment: (Otherwise, the answer is sound - manually create the generic collection type and then resolve that.)

Comment: @TravisIllig Yeah, I'm not sure how I overlooked that to be honest. I've updated my answer.